# Container Div setup with inernal div at 50% left and button bottom right of main container

Tags: html, css

Im trying and failing to set up a container with some content inside.

Container div 300px high, 580px width which has a background image

Internal Div 150px width and height with transparency.
 P text inside this div

Read more button at bottom right of main container.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? What have you tried already? Have you done any research? How can we reproduce the issue you have? To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are after something like this where you would substitute the background-color for a background-image.

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

.internal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;  
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="internal">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="button">Read more</button>
</div>
```